# Enemies can't recover from my attacks

Tags: the-witcher-3

I've run into a problem wth enemies unable to recover from my attacks.
This is the scenario: I dodge their first attack, then I attack, attack, attack, attack ..... win.

It's like they are perma-stunned as long as I don't give them any time to recover.
This is ridiculously easy, I can kill a golem or leshen just by spam attacking, something is wrong. I have like 7% stun chance.

Has anyone heard of such a problem? I am using [Better Combat Evolved](http://www.nexusmods.com/witcher3/mods/769/?) mod on normal, which is harder than blood and broken bones vanilla.

edit: i see this only applies to some enemies. Just met an earth elemental and basilisk that hit back no matter what. Selective bug :P ?

Comment: Maybe it has to do with your difficulty setting?  Try different setting.

Comment: problem solved. Changed from normal to... the hardest whatever its called. Probably mod difficulty changes NPC attack rate.